# Ya APi редактор маршрутов

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь вот на стандартном примере расчета стоимости Яндекс сделать редактирование маршрутов. Режим редактирования не включается. Почему так может быть? Вот код:

```
function init() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
center: [60.906882, 30.067233],
zoom: 9,
type: 'yandex#map',
behaviors: ['scrollZoom', 'drag']
}),
search = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
// useMapBounds: true,
// noCentering: true,
// noPlacemark: true
}),
calculator = new DeliveryCalculator(myMap, myMap.getCenter());

myMap.controls.add(search, { right: 5, top: 5 });

}

function DeliveryCalculator(map, finish) {
this._map = map;
this._start = null;
this._finish = new ymaps.Placemark(finish, { iconContent: 'Б' });
this._route = null;

map.events.add('click', this._onStartPointChange, this);
map.geoObjects.add(this._finish);
}

var ptp = DeliveryCalculator.prototype;

ptp._onStartPointChange = function (e) {
this.setStartPoint(e.get('coordPosition'));
};

ptp.getDirections = function () {
var self = this,
start = this._start.geometry.getCoordinates(),
finish = this._finish.geometry.getCoordinates();

if(this._route) {
this._map.geoObjects.remove(this._route);
}

ymaps.geocode(start, { results: 1 })
.then(function (geocode) {
var address = geocode.geoObjects.get(0) &&
geocode.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('balloonContentBody') || '';

ymaps.route([start, finish])
.then(function (router) {
var distance = Math.round(router.getLength() / 1000),
message = '<span>Расстояние: ' + distance + 'км.</span><br/>' +
'<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: %sр.</span>';

self._route = router.getPaths();
self._route.options.set({ strokeWidth: 5, strokeColor: '0000ffff', opacity: 0.5 });
self._map.geoObjects.add(self._route);
self._start.properties.set('balloonContentBody', address + message.replace('%s', self.calculate(distance)));
//self._start.balloon.open();
router.editor.start({ addWayPoints: true });
});
});
};

ptp.setStartPoint = function (position) {
if(this._start) {
this._start.geometry.setCoordinates(position);
}
else {
this._start = new ymaps.Placemark(position, { iconContent: 'А' }, { draggable: true });
this._start.events.add('dragend', this._onStartPointChange, this);
this._map.geoObjects.add(this._start);
}
this.getDirections();
};

ptp.calculate = function (len) {
// Константы.
var DELIVERY_TARIF = 20,
MINIMUM_COST = 500;

return Math.max(len * DELIVERY_TARIF, MINIMUM_COST);
};

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Т.е. пытаюсь [сюда](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/deliveryCalculator) добавить редактирование маршрута. Как правильно включить редактор в данном примере?

Comment: @New_user, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. Уважайте тех, кого просите о помощи, читать неотформатированный код нет никакого желания.

Comment: Что значит "Режим редактирования"?

Comment: Редактор маршрутов. Перетаскивания маршрута по карте мышкой